# bind multiple fields to bind function

Tags: jquery

I want to send the value of `property_name` to `headline` and `property_name_thumb` when a user types in `property_name`. I works when I only use one but not both?

```
$('#property_name').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() 
{  
    $('#headline','#property_name_thumb').val($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#headline, #property_name_thumb').val($(this).val());
```

All in one string!

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the string after `headline`, so you're passing two parameters instead of one. Use joakimdahlstrom's code instead:

```
$('#headline, #property_name_thumb').val($(this).val()); });
```

The way you did, the first parameter was the selector and the second was the context (kind of a "filter" to your selector - will only select descendants of the context). Since `headline` was not a descendant to `property_name_thumb`, nothing was selected at all, so your code didn't run.